# Include JS Files on Yii

Tags: javascript, yii

I have a question how can i include JS files on Yii, I can not use the default JS or jquery script from Yii.

I have trying to this code-

```
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/panel.js" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript goes in a `<script>` tag not a `<link>` tag

Try:

```
<script src=<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/panel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want:
add this in view file in yii it will add js file after jquery ui

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/js/yourjs.js', ['depends' => [\frontend\assets\JqueryUiAsset::className()]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit?

Comment: yes..can you tell me where you want to add the js file?